# Need help with the following statement in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proposition: If $X$ and $Y$ are sets with the same cardinality (i.e, if there exists a bijection between $X$ and $Y$) then $Sym(X)$ and $Sym(Y)$ are isomorphic

Proof Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a bijective function. Consider the functions

$$\varphi:Sym(X) \rightarrow Sym(Y) \text{,  }\sigma \rightarrow f \circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$$

I don't understand why the latter maps an element from $Sym(X)$ to $Sym(Y)$. $f^{-1}$ takes an element from the set $Y$ and maps it to the set $X$ then $\sigma$ takes that element in x and maps it to some element in $Sym(Y)$, but the domain of $f$ is not the elements in $Sym(Y)$

Comment: $\sigma$ is a permutation on $X$, so It maps elements in $X$ to $X$.

Comment: there is something under the hood  I can't see yet. How is an element from $Sym(Y)$ completely mapped?

Comment: An element in $Sym(Y)$ is a biyection from $Y$ to $Y$, so $f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$ should take an element in $Y$ to another element in $Y$. First $f^{-1}$ sends and element in $Y$ to $X$, then $\sigma$ takes that element in $X$ to another element in $X$, and finally $f$ takes that element into $Y$. It only rests to prove that $f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}$ actually is a permutation (a biyection).

Comment: Got it. I always see these bijections as cycles, but they are functions as well. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

First let's give some intuitive motivation for the map from the proof. Let $\sigma \in \text{Sym}(X)$. We have a bijection $f: X \rightarrow Y$. Now I like to think about this as an element $x \in X$ corresponding or 'being essentially' $f(x) \in Y$, similarly $y \in Y$ corresponds with $f^{-1}(y) \in X$.

Now with this heuristic, to what bijection $\tau \in \text{Sym}(Y)$ does $\sigma$ naturally correspond? Well, if $\sigma$ takes $x$ to $\sigma(x)$, we would like $\tau$ to do 'the same as $\sigma$ with $Y$', that is, we would like $\tau$ to also take $x$ to $\sigma(x)$. This is of course impossible because $x \notin Y$(necessarily), so the best we can do to make $\tau$ look like $\sigma$ is letting $\tau$ take what corresponds with $x$ in $Y$ to what corresponds with $\sigma(x)$ in $Y$, that is, letting $\tau(f(x))=f(\sigma(x))$. Now we know what $\tau$ does with arbitrary $y \in Y$, because 
$$\tau(y)=\tau(f(f^{-1}(y)))=f(\sigma(f^{-1}(y)).$$
So it seems like a good choice to define, for a possible isomorphism $\varphi: \text{Sym}(X) \rightarrow \text{Sym}(Y)$, $\varphi(\sigma)=f \circ \sigma \circ f^{-1}$. Is this a homomorphism? Well, yes, we apply the 'conjugation trick':

$$\varphi(\sigma_1 \circ \sigma _ 2)=f \circ \sigma_1 \circ f^{-1} \circ f \circ \sigma_2 \circ f^{-1}=\varphi(\sigma_1) \circ \varphi(\sigma_2).$$
Is it a bijection? Yes, because one easily checks $\tau \mapsto f^{-1} \circ \tau \circ f$ is a left and right inverse of $\varphi$, basically this is the same as the construction of $\varphi$ except replacing $X$ by $Y$ and $f$ by $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we have two elements of $X$, say, $a$ and $b$, such that $\sigma(a) = b$.

Furthermore, suppose $f(a) = y$ and $f(b) = z$, so that $f^{-1}(y) = a$ and $f^{-1}(z) = b$.

Then $(f \circ \sigma \circ f^{-1})(y) = z$:

$(f \circ \sigma \circ f^{-1})(y) = f(\sigma(f^{-1}(y))) = f(\sigma(a)) = f(b) = z$.

It should be clear that $f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}:Y \to Y$. To show it is a bijection on $Y$, convince yourself that the composition of two bijections is *also* a bijection.